# How to find a group of classes containing specific text using Selenium IDE

Tags: css, xpath, selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to test that the correct title, summary, and link appear in search results. For instance, in the example below, I want to confirm that at least one of the records contains the title "Title for Beta," the summary containing the text "Summary for Beta," and a link called "Link."

```
<ul>
  <li class="results">
    <h2 class="title">Title for Alpha</h2>
    <div class="summary">Summary for Alpha...</li>
    <div class="link"><a href="http://www.example.com">Link</a>
 </li>
 <li class="results">
    <h2 class="title">Title for Beta</h2>
    <div class="summary">Summary for Beta...</li>
    <div class="link"><a href="http://www.example.com">Link</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not a well-formed XML document.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: This is not an XML document. It's HTML. Selenium IDE allows XPath to test HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to select them. One is using the CSS Class.

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

driver.get("...");

List<WebElement> titles = driver.findElements(By.className("title"));
List<WebElement> summarys = driver.findElements(By.className("summary"));
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.className("link"));

for (WebElement webElement : titles) {
    String innerText = webElement.getText();

    // do your test....
}
```

If your page structure is more complicated you can also use XPath to do that.

If you are new to Selenium, you should have a look to the [PageFactory](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) Pattern. This is a nice way to write a much cleaner code.

In the unusual way of selecting Elements by their `InnerText` you can use XPath. 
This XPath selects all elements containing "Title for Alpha" as `InnerText`

```
List<WebElement> titles = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Title for Alpha')]"));
```